# How can I add a Button to a custom scrolling and zooming SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview, custom-view

I wanted to add a custom ImageButton on top of my SurfaceView so it essentially scrolls with the View. The canvas scrolls and zooms with a matrix. How could I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, can you not just do `button.draw(canvas)` in your `SurfaceView.onDraw()` method? You definitely want to bypass the normal layout engine (because it's terribly slow for moving things around) so you'll also have to fake up hit-detection etc.

Comment: ah you are right. However I actually started to rewrite my app for faster draw speeds in OpenGL ES. Is there a way to have a Square made out of 2 triangles act as a button?

Comment: Yup, but you still have to do everything yourself. Translating from pixels back to world coordinates (for touch events etc) can get a bit hairy. I've been kind of hoping someone would have written a GL widget framework by now... maybe they have.